# Angular Html + Css = PDF , problem to generate a proper PDF

Tags: html, css, .net, angular, pdf

I'm developing a web application using .Net core 3.0 (Back-end) and Angular 8 (Front-end).
The user completes a form and then I have to generate a PDF (with design & picture) with the data that he put. The PDF needs to be in high quality.

I have tried several libraries in both Front-end & Back-end.
I need to use a free library.
I think it will be easier and better to do it in the Front-end because the user will need to print it (directly most of the time).
And also, in case of high traffic generate it from the back-end will use too many resources.

Also, "print" the html page is not an option.
I've tried : 
**PdfMake,
kendo-angular-pdf-export,
Jspdf,
wkhtml,
and others..**.

The best ones:

- **Kendo UI**
  It was really the best one, easy to implement and doing exactly what I needed. But is not free and one license is like 900e/user
- **pdfMake**
  The problem with that was that I will have to do all the design with the library-style, So I will have some limitations.
  I would like to be able to generate a pdf from an HTML page including the CSS.

I'm blocked with that pdf generation.
Did someone succeed to generate a proper pdf with a good design with pdfMake?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Don't [re-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59176935/angular-how-to-generate-high-quality-pdf-from-html-css-of-angular-component) the same question when the first one was closed for good reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - How to generate high quality PDF from HTML/CSS of angular component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59176935/angular-how-to-generate-high-quality-pdf-from-html-css-of-angular-component)

Answer (score 0):

A solution I've used is to create a service which, on the back end, generates the HTML and uses headless Chrome to render the PDF. Stream that back to the client browser.

Comment: I will try this. What about the quality and the place of the different elements on the pdf ?

Comment: In my experience, it was perfect. I remember doing some Googling to get the command-line parameters exactly right, but the results were fantastic, and superior to all other products we tried (including Kendo UI and Aspose).